# What can I do about this MRENDIS5 NDIS Protocal Driver Error?

Tags: windows-xp, services

An entry is being added to my System Event 4 times a second like this:

"The MRENDIS5 NDIS Protocol Driver service failed to start due to the following error:
The system cannot find the file specified"

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it says, a service is failing to start.

Take a look in `Computer Management > Services and Applications > Services` and look for anything set to automatic start which is currently disabled/stopped.

Double click on it and try to find out where the file is located / Path to executable as this may give you an idea as to what the file was.

Once you know, you can either reinstall it or install it then perform another uninstall.

This is not a very common error, but you do see it from time to time, it is usually when an uninstall fails or is not written well.

After doing a bit of research for you, it looks like this file is directly related to BT connection management software - This is stuff that comes with the Home Hub / other BT broadband products, I would highly advise doing a full uninstall and removing all of it.

You can also use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Auto runs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and click the `Services` Tab, then look for one that says "File not found" and delete it - but be very careful here, Autoruns is a very powerful tool!